# SpecRun not integrating tests in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: specrun

With SpecRun 1.2 there looks to be support to integrate tests directly is VS test explorer. The only documentation I can find is this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBs2Lwqt5kI - you can see after installing the specRun nuget package, his tests automatically appear in the Test Explorer. For me, that doesn't happen... and I would like it to. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying "Update 4" to visual studio 2012, it started working fine.